# Rename all variables in specific column using clause in standard sql when joining

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Rename all the variables in a specific column (in this case is all variables in date.A) into null values using the clause condition for some further step when joining the tables in BigQuery. So, the query will be like:

```
 SELECT ID, a.date as date.A, b.date as date.B, 
       CASE WHEN a.date <> b.date THEN NULL END AS b.date
FROM
    table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b
 USING (ID)
```

The query is not helpful much for the question, because I know how to rename the column header but haven’t found how to rename the variables in a specific column.

Sample input:

[image]

Sample output:

[image]

NOTE: this question is to rename the variables not for creating new column

Comment: . . I find the question really hard to follow.  Tables contain columns.  Columns contain values for each row in the table.  Values are not "renamed", although columns can be.  In addition, column aliases cannot contain periods (unless the identifiers are escaped).

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a `CASE` expression in the select clause:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    `date.A`,
    CASE WHEN `date.A` = `date.B` THEN `date.A` END AS `date.B`
FROM t;
```

Comment: Edited the question with suggested query, so it will be more clearer. but got this error Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "." at [2:62] at CLAUSE line (CASE WHEN)

Comment: @swm Please try putting your column names in double quotes if they have dot in them.  Check the updated answer.

Comment: Not sure why but apparently i got this error Syntax error: Unexpected string literal "date.B" at [2:67] after END AS

Comment: @swm Apologies...you need to use backticks here.  I am not a guru in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
SELECT
    ..
    CASE WHEN date.A <> date.B THEN NULL 
    ELSE date.B
    END AS date
FROM t
```

Comment: You can do this with just one single check, because a `CASE` expression with no explicit `ELSE` defaults to `ELSE NULL`.

Comment: checked this! Tq